# Group notifications with Expo

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I have a react native messaging app done with Expo. I got notifications to work, but the problem is that each message is a separate notification.

I would like to group notifications sent by the same person. Currently, I have:

```
[Notification]
John - Hey, how are you?

[Notification]
John - Long time no see!
```

and I would like them to merge as a single one when the second message is received, like this:

```
[Notification]
John |
   Hey, how are you?
   Long time to see!
```

I might be missing something because I cannot find anyone else wondering about such a common functionality.

The code I use to send notifications from my backend (python):

```
headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }

session.post(
    "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", 
    json = {
        "to": expo_token, 
        "title": username, 
        "body": message_content, 
    }, 
    headers=headers
)
```

Comment: I have nothing to show really, I am just sending some notification data to the expo endpoint `https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send` and this is the default behavior.
I can copy paste the example from the expo documentation if you want.

Comment: @Tim I added the query that I use to push the notification. There isn't really much to it. The rest is handled by Expo and doesn't require any additional code on my side.

Comment: Yes, that's it. So that if you have 15 messages from 3 senders, you have 3 notifications blocks. Not 15.

Comment: But there is no code in my app that is responsible for displaying notifications. It's entirely done by expo. All I have to do is send some data to the expo API and a notification will be shown. You can start a blank expo project now, and send data to the expo endpoint with the proper Expo Token and it will show a notification on your phone. The only code required is to get the token, and once you have said token you don't even need this code anymore.

Comment: I think you could do something like this with some client-side logic by dismissing duplicate notifications. See https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#dismissing-notifications

Answer (score 0):

In **iOS** you should use **apns-collapse-id**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns

> An identifier you use to coalesce multiple notifications into a single
>   notification for the user. Typically, each notification request causes
>   a new notification to be displayed on the user’s device. When sending
>   the same notification more than once, use the same value in this
>   header to coalesce the requests. The value of this key must not exceed
>   64 bytes.

**Update**
For using collapse feature, you can use for Notifications other service.     Which supports collapse and react native - for example
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/how-notifications-work#section-notification-collapsing

Comment: But this is not with Expo.

Comment: You can use for notifications other service. Any service how support collapse feature for example - https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/how-notifications-work#section-notification-collapsing . OneSignal support collapse & support React Native.

Comment: I'd like to keep using Expo if possible, because of the other features that it offers. Would it work without having to eject from the Expo environment?

Comment: @RyanPergent yes, i think you don't need having to eject from the Expo environment. It should work together.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can not control how notifications group in Expo app now, but I noticed that on IOS they are being grouped together automatically, while on Android you need to set `notification.androidMode` to `collapse`.

Take a look at current documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#androidmode

```
app.json

Path: notification.androidMode
Type: enum

Show each push notification individually (default) or collapse into one (collapse).
```

All your messages will still be separate notifications, but at least they will collapse into one (stack).

That will only work in standalone app, nor in Expo Go.